# MFC Application for Multiple Languages - English, French, Spanish and Korean

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2012, mfc, visual-studio-2013

I am trying to figure out how to do a program that allows a user switchable method for changing from English, French, Spanish and now Korean.  The application is MFC multi-byte character encoding in VS2013.

To do this previously, I had a simple dropdown menu to allow language selection and had a language table internal to the program that had a table of phrases for English, Spanish and French.  Since I inherited this, this was pretty easy to maintain.

However, seeing the need to non-Latin based languages, can anyone offer any ideas for how to implement this for other languages, Particularly Korean and Russian.

Comment: And I would suggest 'upgrading' the app to be Unicode compliant.

Comment: Unicode was the way to go, took a LOT of work, but in the end it was purely the right choise.

Answer (score 0):

This is typically done through MFC's language support for [Localized resources](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8fkteez0.aspx).  A resource only dll can be built that is translated via a tool like [Visual Localize](http://www.visual-localize.de/).